# Deployment tips to support indirect CRLs

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-revocation

I'm looking into the feasibility of using indirect CRLs to eliminate the need to manually publish CRLs from an offline root.

Is anyone familiar with any similar deployments? If so, how did they set it up so the CRL signer doesn't need access to the offline CA's db?

Thanks!

Comment: The last I heard, Windows doesn't support indirect CRLs.  Not that everything revolves around Microsoft of course!  Does your client support it?  I believe OpenSSL does verify indirect CRLs.  If you're using a specific client which supports it then you may have success; but if it's for general use, it may not be worth the effort.

Comment: I confirm that Windows does not support indirect CRLs. This information came directly from Windows PKI team, so be careful with this decision.

Comment: After a little digging, it turns out that OpenSSL only supports indirect CRLs if the issuer is the same entity as the CA.  That is, it can have a different key-pair, but must have the same Subject name.

Comment: I've personally used indirect CRLs in Windows in Windows XP timeframe so I know it at least used to be supported, and I'd be really surprised if they removed it since it's still a supported extension in RFC5280. Most likely MS Certificate Server doesn't support creating those CRLs, so they'd have to be done manually or with some other tool. OpenSSL's lack of support is unfortunate as that effectively makes indirect CRLs useless for this scenario.

Comment: I believe Windows supports it in the same way as OpenSSL - if the issuer is the same entity as the CA but has a different key.

Comment: Ah, never mind, my memory is faulty. I did play around with the IDP extenstion, but I checked with the dev who wrote the crypt32 code and was reminded we never supported indirect CRLs. Windows only supports CRLs signed by the same CA key that signed the subject cert.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is not supported by most clients (Windows, OpenSSL) so using indirect CRLs is not an option.

Comment: I have found no sources to support your claim, and looking at libraries that handle X.509 it seems they all have code for handling that. Especially OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1):

Some digging results on Indirect CRLs:

1. Status as of May 2020: [Indirect CRL CLI and support](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2020-May/012371.html) (message seems to be unanswered on the openssl-users mailing list)
2. Post of November 2017: [Re: [openssl.org #3097] Incorrect revocation
   status with indirect CRL](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Re-openssl-org-3097-Incorrect-revocation-status-with-indirect-CRL-td47482.html)
3. An earlier post of May 2011: [Handling
   Indirect CRL Issuer](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Handling-Indirect-CRL-Issuer-tp24161p24163.html)

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Include the relevant parts of the links in your answer here.